# Reading windows registry values by making remote connection from CentOS

Tags: windows, security, connection, registry

I need to access windows registry values of a computer by remotely connecting to it through some windows utility or any other alternative.
Also, the remote connection should be secure.It should not make the system vulnerable post making the connection.

Comment: There are thousands of ways to do this.  What are you really trying to do? Because exposing a remote registry key on a Windows PC to a Linux box is rather unusual - save for maybe compliance and auditing scenarios.  If we knew what you were really trying to do, we could happily advise better....

Comment: hey, I just want to remotely scan the registry values of a windows machine to check the maturity of that windows system (on security parameters).Also I have a management tool on my Linux system,CentOS.Hence I want to login to that windows machine ,scan it(via some script) or WMIC commands.The only problem I am facing is to choose connection mode,so that my purpose gets satisfied as well as it should not leave any security loophole.